# Display goes out of Range

Tags: display, opengles

We have a Raspberry Pi 2 running `Rasbian Jessie` with the OpenGL driver.

It is connected to a HDMI to DisplayPort Adaptor and an odd size touch screen display (1280x800).

We are running `lightdm` and it starts up a full screen application.

This application is built using Rust and makes use of the OpenGL driver.

After this application has been running for about an hour, the display suddenly goes `Out of Range`. After about 10 - 15 minutes, the screen then works again with no issues.

This is happening on 2 independent sets of hardware, although the SD cards are clones.

What could cause the display to go `Out of Range` an hour after it has started, but then continue running a few minutes later?

Following that, are there any mitigation techniques we can use?

Comment: What do you mean by out of range?

Comment: Out of Range is displayed on the display. Similar to https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=25709&p=234476. Except it happens after an hour not on boot.

Comment: I'd love to get a bug report about this at https://github.com/anholt/linux/issues/ with your dmesg (at point of failure) and xrandr --verbose (both at boot and when failed) attached.  Also the output of cat /debug/clk/clk_summary (with debugfs mounted there) when things are working and when they're not working.

Answer (score -1):

If you're dealing with the same issue but with raspbian OS. You have to change the config.txt file in the boot file-system drive (windows). Change what? If you have some other fresh installation of raspbian that works, copy the config file and paste it into the one that doesn't work. If you don't have a working-copy of config.txt file then copy below config.txt exactly the same.

```
dtparam=audio=on
```

Comment: Remember, it's not HDMI issue, your pi is not broke or anything, your LCD/LED is okay. It justs an issue with hdmi_mode and config.txt configurations, commenting and uncommenting lines in config.txt didn't work for me so here's my fix. Also you can install a new raspbian OS and everything would work awesome but above is a quick fix.